# Why is casting double to char allowed in Java?

Tags: java, casting, char, double

Why is `char c = (char)65.8;` allowed in Java?

Shouldn't it throw an error since `65.8` is not an exact Unicode value? I understand that the double is truncated to an integer, in this case, `65`, but it seems like bad design to me to allow the programmer to make such a cast.

Comment: Maybe the language designers implement the features anyway in case someone find a use for it with the expense of higher probability of mistakes made by novice programmers. I do agree it would be nicer if some sort of compiler warnings are given in this scenario

Comment: BTW—Java uses Unicode, not ASCII. Java's `char` datatype stores one UTF-16 code-unit, one or two of which encode a Unicode codepoint. One base codepoint and zero or more combining codepoints form a grapheme, which is what people think of when using the term "character."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is called **Narrowing type casting**. 
From [**`oracle docs`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3):

> 22 specific conversions on primitive types are called the narrowing
>   primitive conversions:
>
> short to byte or char
>
> char to byte or short
>
> int to byte, short, or char
>
> long to byte, short, char, or int
>
> float to byte, short, char, int, or long
>
> double to byte, short, char, int, long, or float
>
> A narrowing primitive conversion may lose information about the
>   overall magnitude of a numeric value and may also lose precision and
>   range.

In Java, there are two basic types of type conversions: **widening** and **narrowing**.

A **`widening conversion`** occurs when you convert from a type with smaller (or narrower) to type with larger (or wider) range. Because of this, there is no chance for data loss and the conversion is considered **"safe."**

A **`narrowing conversion`** occurs when you convert from a type with larger (or wider) to type with smaller (or narrower) range. Since we are shrinking the range, there is a chance of data loss so this conversion is considered **"unsafe"**

[image: narrowing type conversion]

The conversion from **byte** to **char** is a special case and represents **widening** and **narrowing** at the same time. The conversion starts by converting the **byte** to an **int** and then the **int** gets converted to the **char**.

One reason I can think of why narrowing type casting doesn't result in an error/exception is to allow for a convenient/easy/quick type conversion in the cases when no data will be loss. Compiler leaves it up to us to make sure converted data will be able to fit in the smaller range. It is also useful if we want to quickly truncate values such as rounding the value of a `double` (by type-casting it to an `int`).

Comment: Where would char go for the widening and narrowing casts?

Comment: in between `byte` and `short`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: That makes sense, since `char` is 16 bits. But then why do we need to explicity cast a `byte` to a `char`, even though it should be a widening conversion?

Comment: I see, and the same case would be present with casting a `short` to a `char`, correct? Also, does this mean that whenever a `byte` (or `short`, depending on whether or not my assumption is correct) is explicitly cast to another type, it will always be first cast to an `int` and then the final type, or is this special case only used with `char`s?

Comment: No, the `byte` to `char` is the one special case including both narrowing and widening. As provided via link in my answer, you can find much more detail at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3

Comment: One more question: why is `byte x = 'A';` allowed without an explicit cast, even though a `char` is "higher up" than a `byte`? Therefore, wouldn't it make sense to have `char` "below" `byte` rather than between `short` and `byte`?

Answer (score 4):

it doesn't happen automatically on assignment: that would be a compilation error.

The fact that the programmer makes a conscious choice (e.g. the type cast) means she is taking into consideration the possibility of, and responsibility for, possible truncation.

Comment: Would it be considered bad practice to cast a double to a char?

Comment: it seems unusual, but I'm sure there's a legitimate use case out there.

Answer (score 2):

You may have code such as cipher algorithms that may find useful to cast a `double` or `float` to `char`. Also, `char` is an unsigned type, which means `(char)200.5` yields something different than `(char)(byte)200.5`.

Answer (score 1):

How can the dumb computer know what was intended?

```
char c = (char)65.8; // valid, double gets converted and explicitly truncated to a char
```

It may so happen that during a calculation, you might be doing some complex computations involving double arithmetic and finally on the final value, you apply the trucation and display as a character. What's wrong?

Comment: It's a pretty valid question to ask why this computation is expressed as a type cast rather than as a call to a static method.